# How to use register with CTRL-A or CTRL-X in vim

Tags: vim

Suppose that I have a number into register `r`.

How could I use this value with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

Here's an example to make it clearer:

Suppose that I have this text file:

```
10
13
15
```

I want to to increase those numbers with the value in register `r` to obtain (if it contains 5)

```
15
18
20
```

Why I'm asking it ? Because I want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> into a macro but the number of time that I need to apply <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> is only know at "run time".

In a more general way, how could I execute a command a number of times stored in a register ?

All of these questions and answers where interesting but they don't answer my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405952/vim-register-use-in-ex-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a mapping like this:

```
noremap <Leader><C-A> :<C-U>execute 'normal!' str2nr(getreg('r')) . '<C-A>'<CR>
```

It maps <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Control-A</kbd> (`<Leader>` defaults to <kbd>\</kbd>, see `:help leader`) to run the usual <kbd>Control-A</kbd> the number of times specified in the `r` register. You could even use this to rebind the default <kbd>Control-A</kbd> (leave out `<Leader>`), but that seems like it could lead to confusion later if you ever forget about the mapping.

When the `r` register contains `5`, it works like this (switched to double-quote notation since it is impossible to represent <kbd>Control-A</kbd> in a single-quoted string literal):

The `getreg()` and `str2nr()` functions are evaluated, resulting in this Ex command:

```
:execute 'normal!' 5 . "\<C-A>"
```

This results in another Ex command:

```
:normal! "5\<C-A>"
```

This executes a normal-mode command:

> 5<kbd>Control-A</kbd>

Which uses the prefix count before the usual <kbd>Control-A</kbd> (non-mapped, due do the `!` in `:normal!`).

This version always uses the value in the `r` register; it explicitly ignores any prefixed count (unlike the usual <kbd>Control-A</kbd>). Alternate implementations are possible (e.g. where a prefixed count overrides or multiplies the value in the `r` register), but they would be a bit more complex.

---

You could also put the command directly in your macro instead of using a mapping:

> qq…:execute 'normal!' str2nr(getreg('r')) . '<kbd>Control-A</kbd>'<kbd>Return</kbd>…

You have to type the actual <kbd>Control-A</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> instead of their `<>` equivalents because this is no longer part of a mapping where Vim will automatically make the translation. Also, the <kbd>Control-U</kbd> is dropped, since it was only there to guard against a possible prefix count before the initial <kbd>:</kbd> (you can protect against this in the macro content itself).

Comment: I realize that your answer deserves thousand of votes.